# Spring Boot Thymeleaf: Unable to pick up templates from sub-folders under resources/templates

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf v3.0.11.RELEASE Spring Boot v2.1.3.RELEASE, and I am facing issues with my templates placed under classpath:templates/folder1/folder2/.

I tried the below approaches

- Setting up the property `spring.thymeleaf.prefix` to `classpath:/templates/**/`, `classpath:/templates/*` and other similar patterns
- Tried adding the template resolver in application startup class.

  ```
  @Bean
  public TemplateEngine emailTemplateEngine() {
      final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
      templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
      return templateEngine;
  }

  private ITemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
      final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
      templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns(Collections.singleton("/*"));
      templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
      templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
      templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
      return templateResolver;
  ```

  }

These approaches aren't working and I am still getting error:

```
"Error resolving template [template_name], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers"
```

Am I missing something? I just need to know the way to enable wildcards for the suffix.

Note: It works if I hard code `classpath:templates/folder1/folder2`, but I can't since there are going to be multiple folders and I don't want to fixate all the folder names.

Answer (score 1):

Mine didn't work until I changed `templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");` to `templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");` and renamed the views folder to `templates`.

I have no idea why but this is the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

add the following configuration class in your app

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

  @Bean
  public SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringResourceTemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver =
        new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(
        StandardTemplateModeHandlers.HTML5.getTemplateModeName());
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    return templateResolver;
  }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, getting error as `class path resource [templates/*template-name.html] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Comment: share the code where you are trying to process`[templates/*template-name.html]`